# How can I check if a server exists in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I am writing a function that tests for brokens links in an org-mode buffer:

```
    (setq urls '("http://google.com" "http://bing.com" "http://www.yahoo.com"  "http://thisdoesntexist.net"))
    (while (setq nextlink (car urls))
      (if (url-http-file-exists-p nextlink)
          (message "Link works: %s" nextlink)
        (message "Broken Link found: %s" nextlink))
      (setq urls (cdr urls)))
```

This works except when it encounters a non-existent web server.  Then it throws a lisp error and opens up a *backtrace* buffer.

What I would like is way to first test if the server exists and if so then use url-http-file-exists-p to check for a specific document.

Thanks

- Edited to add solution that works for me.  Thanks Dov!

  `(while (setq nextlink (car urls))
    (condition-case nil
      (if (url-http-file-exists-p nextlink)
          (message "Link works: %s" nextlink)
        (message "Broken Link found: %s" nextlink))
      ((error) (message "Server not found: %s" nextlink)))
      (setq urls (cdr urls)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just catch the error through an exception handling `condition-case` block?